# VIM how to remove leading ^G

Tags: vim, macvim

These seem to be white spaces but I can't get rid of them.
[image]

Comment: I found an interesting post on reddit. (https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/a4yzyt/g_characters_prefixing_directory_and_file_names/). He has a similar problem and there are multiple solutions. It might help you.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to add this line in .vimrc:

```
let g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter = "\u00a0"
```

Description to the problem from the link Malte Kölle shared:

> Nerdtree uses C-g as a delimiter between items in the tree's nodes.
>   [...] you could write this line in your vimrc to replace the C-g
>   characters with no-break spaces: let g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter =
>   "\u00a0"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:
Get the code of your "supposed space char" typing `ga` or even better, copy it to a register, let's say `a`, by doing

```
"ayl ...............
```

Now we can substitute every ocurrence of it

```
 :%s/<ctrl-r>a/new-pattern/g

 : .................. command
 % .................. the whole file
 <ctrl-r>a .......... type Ctrl-r plus a
 new-pattern ........ whatever you want
```

In case you have just get the code you will have to use the propper scape simbol to use in the substituition. for example, the hexadecimal windows end of line symbol is: `%x20`

Answer (score 0):

To delete leading whitespace, try this in the insert mode / ex mode:

```
:%s/^\s\+//e
```

"e" flag tells the find-replace command that: not finding a match is not an error.